# аналог tcpListener.Pending() в Socket C#

Tags: c#, сокет

Нужен аналогический метод к tcpListener.Pending() но в классе Socket.
Нужно проверять есть ли входящие подключения, так-же возвращает переменную типа bool.

Есть ли функция в Socket для проверки наличия входящие сообщений, если да, то какая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто посмотрите исходники `TcpListener.Pending()`, и используйте со своим сокетом:

```
return m_ServerSocket.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectRead);
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs,228

Comment: Спасибо, работает, а есть ли функция на проверку входящих сообщений, чтобы прием можно было сделать

Comment: foreach(Socket client in Clients){ if(client.CheckMessages){Console.WriteLine(result)} }

Comment: CheckMessages - это для примера, этот код то пример.

Comment: @Gweston в сокета есть свойство `Available`, кажется это то, что вам нужно

Comment: Да, работает, еще раз спасибо большое.